# Google Drive API v2: InsertMediaUpload - Null response received

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Using: Drive v2: 1.5.0.99 Beta,  .NET Framework: 4.5

The authentication takes place properly (using impersonation) -  via service account (AssertionFlowClient).
Access token is obtained.  Service account has been granted domain wide privileges

I am able to get the parent folder - ID  (strRootFolder) via Service.Files.List();

```
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File flUpload = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
flUpload.Title = Title;
flUpload.Description = Description;
flUpload.MimeType = MimeType;
flUpload.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = strRootFolder } };

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload drvRequest = drvService.Files.Insert(flUpload, new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray), "text/plain");
drvRequest.Upload();
```

However Upload method does not send any request. No exception is thrown. Fiddler trace shows no request has been sent and hence request.responsebody is always null.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: You should be using the Google drive api v3 not v2

Answer (score 1):

If some exception occur during the upload, the return object (IUploadProgress) should contain the exception (take a look at the Exception property). 
Please check what is the exception.

You should also consider using UploadAsync which doesn't block your code (but first you should understand what is the exception)

Comment: No exception is thrown - nothing happens. ResponseBody is null

Comment: What the return object contains? it has Status, Exception and BytesSent. What each of those properties contain?

Comment: Have managed to resolve this. With UploadAsync it threw an exception that ZLibPortable reference was not available. However with InsertMediaUpload.Upload method it does not throw any exception nor does it send any request  - just return null. Looks like some fix is required in InsertMediaUpload. If ZLibPortable Ref is added InsertMediaUpload.Upload works fine.

Comment: Don't you use NuGet? In that case the required reference will be added to your project automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Exception from your upload, that will give you a better idea of the actual problem.

Sample code:

```
var progress = request.Upload();

if (progress.Exception != null)
{
   //Log execption, or break here to debug
   YourLoggingProvider.Log(progress.Exception.Message.ToString());
}
```