# Null ResponseBody sometimes, when uploading file using Google Drive .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm sometimes getting null ResponseBody when I send some files to google drive.

This happens randomly, most of the files are sent, but 1 in 10 files return null ResponseBody.

I searched for this, but there are only questions about aways getting response null [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662041/null-response-creating-file-using-google-drive-net-api), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021931/google-drive-api-v2-insertmediaupload-null-response-received)

My code:

```
await UploadFileAsync(...); //exception here

public Task<string> UploadFileAsync(DriveService driveService, string LocalPath, string gdriveFileName, string GDriveFolder, IProgress<long> progress)
{
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var folderId = GetDirectoryOrCreateIfNotExist(driveService, GDriveFolder);
                var file = CreateGDriveFile(gdriveFileName, folderId);

                IUploadProgress result = null;
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
                using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(LocalPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    request = driveService.Files.Create(file, stream, "image/jpeg");
                    request.ChunkSize = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize * 4;

                    request.ProgressChanged += (p) => progress.Report(p.BytesSent * 100 / stream.Length);

                    request.Fields = "id, webContentLink, name";
                    result = request.Upload();
                }

                if (request == null)
                    throw new Exception("O request é nulo");

                if (request.ResponseBody == null)
                    throw new Exception("O ResponseBody é nulo"); //Throw here sometimes

                var fileUploaded = request.ResponseBody;

                return fileUploaded.WebContentLink;
            });
}

private string GetDirectoryOrCreateIfNotExist(DriveService driveService, string folderName)
        {
            var folder = GetFolderIdByName(driveService, folderName).FirstOrDefault();

            if (folder == null)
            {
                folder = CreateGDriveDirectory(driveService, folderName);
                AplyPermissionToFile(driveService, folder);
            }

            return folder;
        }

private File CreateGDriveFile(string fileName, string folderName = null)
        {
            var file = new File()
            {
                Name = fileName
            };

            if (folderName != null)
            {
                file.Parents = new List<string>
                {
                    folderName
                };
            }

            return file;
        }
```

Why is ResponseBody null? and Why does this happen only a few times?

**Update:**

I Edit the UploadFileAsync(), to check for UploadStatus, now I'm getting:

```
The service drive has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Internal Error [500]
Errors [
    Message[Internal Error] Location[ - ] Reason[internalError] Domain[global]
]
```

updated code: (see result.Status != UploadStatus.Completed)

```
public Task<string> UploadFileAsync(DriveService driveService, string LocalPath, string gdriveFileName, string GDriveFolder, IProgress<long> progress)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var folderId = GetDirectoryOrCreateIfNotExist(driveService, GDriveFolder);
                var file = CreateGDriveFile(gdriveFileName, folderId);

                IUploadProgress result = null;
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
                using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(LocalPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    request = driveService.Files.Create(file, stream, "image/jpeg");
                    request.ChunkSize = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize * 4;

                    request.ProgressChanged += (p) => progress.Report(p.BytesSent * 100 / stream.Length);

                    request.Fields = "id, webContentLink, name";
                    result = request.Upload();
                }

                if (result.Status != UploadStatus.Completed) //check status, now it's throwing here sometimes
                    throw result.Exception;

                if (request == null)
                    throw new Exception("O request é nulo");

                if (request.ResponseBody == null)
                    throw new Exception("O ResponseBody é nulo");

                var fileUploaded = request.ResponseBody;

                return fileUploaded.WebContentLink;
            });
        }
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that [500 Error Code](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_500_error_backend_error) because this is an issue related to [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#exponential-backoff). It will happen due to the fact of the quantity of the concurrent requests you are attempting to make.

Therefore, In your code, you will need to apply some logic to avoid that issue. Like for example this [algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff#example_algorithm):

> If the request fails, wait 1 + random_number_milliseconds seconds and
>   retry the request.
>
> If the request fails, wait 2 + random_number_milliseconds seconds and
>   retry the request.
>
> If the request fails, wait 4 + random_number_milliseconds seconds and
>   retry the request.
>
> And so on, up to a maximum_backoff time.
>
> where:
>
> The wait time is min(((2^n)+random_number_milliseconds),
>   maximum_backoff), with n incremented by 1 for each iteration
>   (request).
>
> random_number_milliseconds is a random number of milliseconds less
>   than or equal to 1000. This helps to avoid cases where many clients
>   get synchronized by some situation and all retry at once, sending
>   requests in synchronized waves. The value of
>   random_number_milliseconds is recalculated after each retry request.
>
> maximum_backoff is typically 32 or 64 seconds. The appropriate value
>   depends on the use case.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! and thank you for sharing your modified code

Answer (score 2):

Based on  [alberto vielma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11058516/alberto-vielma)'s answer, my code now works and looks like this:

```
    public Task<string> UploadFileAsync(DriveService driveService, string LocalPath, string gdriveFileName, string GDriveFolder, IProgress<long> progress)
    {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var folderId = GetDirectoryOrCreateIfNotExist(driveService, GDriveFolder);
                var file = CreateGDriveFile(gdriveFileName, folderId);

                IUploadProgress result = null;
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
                using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(LocalPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    request = driveService.Files.Create(file, stream, "image/jpeg");
                    request.ChunkSize = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize * 4;

                    request.ProgressChanged += (p) => progress.Report(p.BytesSent * 100 / stream.Length);

                    request.Fields = "id, webContentLink, name";
                    result = request.Upload();

                    //solution: Truncated exponential backoff
                    if (result.Status != UploadStatus.Completed)
                    {
                        var rdn = new Random();
                        var waitTime = 0;
                        var count = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            waitTime = (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, count)) * 1000) + rdn.Next(0, 1000);
                            Thread.Sleep(waitTime);

                            result = request.Upload();
                            count++;

                        } while (count < 5 && (result.Status != UploadStatus.Completed));
                    }//end solution
                }

                if (result.Status != UploadStatus.Completed)
                    throw result.Exception; //Doesn't get here anymore

                var fileUploaded = request.ResponseBody;

                return fileUploaded.WebContentLink;
            });
    }
```